# The Determinant of a Special Vandermonde Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Consider the following  Vandermonde matrix 
$$
V_n = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^{n-2} & x_1^{n-1} \\
  1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & \cdots & x_2^{n-2} & x_2^{n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^{n-2} & x_n^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

It is well-known [[1](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant)] that the determinant of $V_n$ is defined by 
$$
\displaystyle V_n = \prod_{1 \mathop \le i \mathop < j \mathop \le n} \left({x_j - x_i}\right)\tag{1}
$$

Let $V_{n-1}^{(i,j)}$ be a square matrix such that it is obtained by the removing  $i$th row and $j$th column of $V_n$.

*My question:* Is it possible to get a closed-form for the determinant of $V_{n-1}^{(i,j)}$ similar to $(1)$.

*My try:* If $j=n$ then $V_{n-1}^{(i,n)}$ is a Vandermonde matrix and there is a closed-form for its  determinant as $(1)$.

Thanks for any suggestions.

**Edit:** I think the general case of the proposed question is as follows; what is the closed-form of the determinant of the next matrix

$$
w_n = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & x_1^{i_1} & x_1^{i_2} & \cdots & x_1^{i_{n-2}} & x_1^{i_{n-1}} \\
  1 & x_2^{i_1} & x_2^{i_2} & \cdots & x_2^{i_{n-2}} & x_2^{i_{n-1}} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  1 & x_n^{i_1} & x_n^{i_2} & \cdots & x_n^{i_{n-2}} & x_n^{i_{n-1}}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
where $i_t$, for $1\leq t \leq n-1$, are positive integer numbers such that 
$i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_{n-2}<i_{n-1}$.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate of something posted a month ago or something like it..?

Comment: @mathreadler I appreciate to help me to find that question. Thsnks

Comment: The determinant of the general form of Vandermonde matrix is the product of the ordinary Vandermonde determinant and a [Schur polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial).

Comment: Do you have the solutions? I encounter [the same problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505274/determinant-of-vandermonde-matrix-with-deleted-rows).

Answer (score 1):

The question is to give the [first minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) of Vandermonde matrix.

Note that for all square matrix $\mathbf {A}$, ${\mathbf {A} \operatorname {adj} (\mathbf {A} )=\det(\mathbf {A} )\,\mathbf {I}}$, and $\operatorname {adj} (\mathbf {A} )=[{\mathbf {C} _{ij}]^{\mathsf {T}}=[(-1)^{i+j}\mathbf {M} _{ji}}]$ where $\mathbf {M} _{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$ minor of $\mathbf {A}$.

And [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde%27s_Matrix) is the inverse of Vandermonde matrix.