# Determinant of Vandermonde matrix with deleted rows

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

Given a partition$\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n)$, where $\lambda_1\geqslant\lambda_2\geqslant\cdots\lambda_n$, and each $\lambda_j$ is a non-negative integer, the Vandermonde matrix with deleted rows can be defined by

$\mathbf{V}=\left[ \begin{matrix} x_1^{\lambda_1+n-1} & x_2^{\lambda_1+n-1} & \dots & x_n^{\lambda_1+n-1} \\
x_1^{\lambda_2+n-2} & x_2^{\lambda_2+n-2} & \dots & x_n^{\lambda_2+n-2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_1^{\lambda_n} & x_2^{\lambda_n} & \dots & x_n^{\lambda_n} \end{matrix} \right]$
.

The determinant of the matrix $\mathbf{V}$ can be determined by the [Schur polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial). However, from the Jacobi−Trudi identities, the determinant of the matrix $\mathbf{V}$ is just expressed as a determinant in terms of the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial), which is still hard to be checked whether the determinant is zero or not. Is there any way that can check whether the matrix $\mathbf{V}$ is full rank or not?

Specifically, I assume that $x_i=e^{j2\pi\frac{i}{n}}$, $\forall i\in [1,2,\cdots,n]$.

Comment: Do you know anything about the $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ ?

Comment: With the new assumption, the problem may be simplified.

Comment: I think you are looking for the Chebotarev theorem (Theorem 2.8 in [Victor Prasolov, *Problems and Theorems in Linear Algebra*](http://staff.math.su.se/mleites/books/prasolov-1994-problems.pdf)).

Comment: Thank you very much. However, $n$ is assumed to be a prime in the Chebotarev theorem. What would happen if $n$ is assumed to be a positive integer?

Comment: Ah, you're right. This is not the most general setup.