# Determinant of Vandermonde Matrix with expantion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

How to determine the determinant formula of a Vandermonde matrix of size $N\times N$ by removing the $p$-th row and $q$-th column?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: If $W=(p^q)$, where $p=1,2,\ldots,N$, $q=0,1,\ldots,N-1$ and $W^{-1}=(b_{i,j})$, then the required determinant is $(-1)^{i+j}b_{i,j}|W|$. References on calculating the inverse matrix to the Vandermonde matrix can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix#Resulting_properties).

Comment: This seems to be [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581280/the-determinant-of-a-special-vandermonde-matrix?rq=1)